# What is the difference between and array containing dot after the number e.g. [ 1. 2. ] and an array without dot e.g. [ 1 2 ]?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, genfromtxt

I'm trying to import data from csv file and I get two different types of arrays when I use pandas' read function and numpy's getfromtxt resulting in two different arrays:

```
[[ 1.  0.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  1.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1. ...,  1.  0.  0.]]
```

When I use the following line of code:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
df = genfromtxt('C:/Users/m15x/Desktop/UFABC/PDPD/inputX(editado_bits).csv', delimiter=',')

X = df

print(X)
```

And:

```
[[1 0 1 ..., 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ..., 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 ..., 1 0 0]
 ..., 
 [1 0 1 ..., 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 ..., 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 ..., 1 0 0]]
```

When I use the this line of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/m15x/Desktop/UFABC/PDPD/input(editado_bits).csv')

X1 = df.loc[0:86,'Initiation (Gradual)' : 'Otoscopy (cerumen)']
X = X1.values

print(X)
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: No dot means integers and they are exact values so long as they are small enough.  Dot means float and considering that machines are binary, they are inexact, but very close.

Answer (score 0):

Try in Python shell:

```
>>> type(1.)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
```